# Youtube API liveChatMessages().list() returns 400 error

Tags: python, youtube-livestreaming-api

I'm currently trying to use the following API call to grab my current livestream's chat messages.

```
liveChatMessages().list(
    part='id',
    liveChatId=<my_livestream_id>,
    )
chat_message_list = request.execute()
print(chat_message_list)
```

But it returns the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "page token is not valid.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "page token is not valid.",
        "domain": "youtube.liveChat",
        "reason": "pageTokenInvalid"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

There's nothing in the liveChatMessages.list documentation about this particular error. Could a Google engineer monitoring this tag please shed some light on this issue? I am currently livestreaming right now, so the livestream/chat should exist.

Comment: hm.... I am facing exactly the same issue - I was thinking this is a result if me being already on the chat itself so the actual youtube window already made the first request to get the messages without needing a page token. the only thing is that I don't know how to circumvent this... maybe use different credential for the API...

Comment: I went ahead and tried it on a different person's stream with both my main account and my other youtube account (which is an authorized test user) via the API documentation's test code feature. Still getting the same error and it's driving me nuts. There's basically no documentation or help for this issue anywhere.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue, this is so frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

This can probably have more reasons, but in my case the `liveChatId` was wrong. I was taking `items[0].id` (which has a length of 11), however the correct value is in `items[0].snippet.liveChatId` (length of 55).